# Passing a pointer to a typedef'ed array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

After initializing a 4x4 array of unsigned chars on the stack, I would like to pass a pointer to the array to another function. I do not understand why this is failing.

From my point of view, it should be the same as passing a pointer to any other array (the address of where the array is starting).

Though when trying to pass it, it seems only the first place in the array is at the correct location, and I access random memory on all other places.

What am I doing wrong here? Any explanation why this is?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char multi_array[4][4];


void print_array(multi_array* arr){
    unsigned char i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("%d ", *arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    unsigned char i,j,z;
    multi_array arr;    // Aren't we allocating memory on the stack for a 4x4 u_char array?

    z = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            arr[i][j] = z++;
        }
    }

    print_array(&arr); // Arent we passing the address of the beginning of the array here?
    return 0;
}
```

`OUTPUT: 0 4 8 12 48 255 0 0 48 55 23 108 0 0 56 255`

Comment: What, exactly, do you think you're accomplishing with that `typedef` line?

Comment: Just for an alias :)

Comment: In print_array(), arr is a pointer to multi_array type. So change printf to `printf("%d ", (*arr)[i][j]);`

Comment: If this is a 4x4 matrix, you can wrap it within a struct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hiding arrays or pointers behind a typedef is bad practice. You just found out one of many reasons why.

`multi_array* arr` in your example is equivalent to `unsigned char(*arr)[4][4]`, an array pointer. You cannot de-reference it through `*arr[i][j]` because of operator precedence. `[]` having higher precedence than `*`. You would have to do `(*arr)[i][j]` instead.

The proper solution is to not use a typedef at all, but instead use this:

```
void print_array (size_t x, size_t y, unsigned char arr[x][y]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < y; j++){
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In statement `printf("%d ", *arr[i][j]);` operator `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. This means that operations are performed in wrong order.

Use `(*arr)[i][j]` instead.

As a general rule, hiding pointers or arrays behind typedef is a bad practice, because it's not obvious what the type is. If you want to use typedef, wrap it in struct definition.